# How does one configure a pin as an input with a pull-up using Linux's gpiod library?

Tags: linux-kernel, gpio

Looking at the function `devm_gpiod_get`, it is possible to configure the initial mode of the pin using one of the variants of the `gpiod_flags` enum:

```c
/**
 * Optional flags that can be passed to one of gpiod_* to configure direction
 * and output value. These values cannot be OR'd.
 */
enum gpiod_flags {
    GPIOD_ASIS  = 0,
    GPIOD_IN    = GPIOD_FLAGS_BIT_DIR_SET,
    GPIOD_OUT_LOW   = GPIOD_FLAGS_BIT_DIR_SET | GPIOD_FLAGS_BIT_DIR_OUT,
    GPIOD_OUT_HIGH  = GPIOD_FLAGS_BIT_DIR_SET | GPIOD_FLAGS_BIT_DIR_OUT |
              GPIOD_FLAGS_BIT_DIR_VAL,
    GPIOD_OUT_LOW_OPEN_DRAIN = GPIOD_OUT_LOW | GPIOD_FLAGS_BIT_OPEN_DRAIN,
    GPIOD_OUT_HIGH_OPEN_DRAIN = GPIOD_OUT_HIGH | GPIOD_FLAGS_BIT_OPEN_DRAIN,
};
```

What seems to be missing here is the ability to set a pin as an input with a pull up. The closest correct configuration seems to be `GPIOD_OUT_HIGH_OPEN_DRAIN`, but this doesn't seem quite right. How can I configure a pin to be an input with a pull-up using Linux's GPIO library?

Comment: The function `gpiod_direction_input` seems to apply the pull up / pull down setting via `lflags`, but as far as I can tell this can only be set through ACPI (and perhaps a DT)...

Comment: The flags for open drain and pull bias seem to be mostly descriptive in the GPIO drivers (with the descriptive bits set in ACPI or DT). If they are hardware-configurable, they are configured by the pin control drivers.